# Cron schedule - Execute job at three different times with no pattern between. Is it possible?

Tags: cron, execute, schedule

I have a job I want to run using Quartz, which require the time to be specified using a Cron schedule.

The job should run at 17:00, 17:35 and 22:05.

Is it possible to specify these times using a Cron schedule ? I've already looked into the Wikipedia article, but it did not help much. From my point of view, there needs to be a pattern between the times, so that you can specify them using a Cron schedule.

Best regards

Nicolas

Comment: Can't you just enter 3 cron jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with 3 cron jobs. example :

```
> crontab -e

00 17 * * * sh  /example/script.sh
35 17 * * * sh  /example/script.sh
05 22 * * * sh  /example/script.sh
```